# How to move item of listbox by python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have following python code in Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('200x200')

label_var = tk.StringVar()
l = tk.Label(window, bg='yellow', width=4, textvariable=label_var)
l.pack()
```

I want to move item of listbox when I click **Next item** button, but the item sill stop at **item 1** No moving (move to item2)

```
def move():
    value = lb.get(lb.curselection())
    label_var.set(value)

    # move items of listbox 1, 2, 3, 4
    index = lb.curselection()[0] 
    lb.select_set(index + 1)  # move to item2 but default still stop at items 1


var = tk.StringVar()
var.set((1,2,3,4))
lb = tk.Listbox(window, listvariable=var)
lb.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(window, text='Next item', command=move)
b1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

How to solve it.

Comment: which item do you want to move where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what your method should look like -

```
def move():
    value = lb.get(lb.curselection())
    x1 = lb.curselection()[0]
    lb.selection_clear(x1)
    if x1+1==lb.size():
        lb.selection_set(0)
    else:
        lb.selection_set(x1+1)
    label_var.set(value)
```

Please note that, you need to handle corner cases, i.e. end of the list. In this code, at the end of the list, I restart at beginning.